# Check updated String parameter of an 'edit' uicontrol while it is active

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm having a bit of trouble with Matlab's `uicontrol` handling. Here's the situation:

My (programmatic) GUI contains an **editable text field**. This field originally contains a **numeric value** and is supposed to always contain one. In order to ensure that, the `'String'` parameter is to be repeatedly checked, converted to numeric, and re-entered into the `'String'` property of the `uicontrol`. This is supposed to happen whenever a user enters a visible character into the text field.

Additionally, the program is supposed to notice at any point whether the current value of said text field differs from the original value, which is stored in memory. If the user closes the figure, a **modal dialog** opens and asks if he wants to save the change to that value or discard it. If the figure is then reopened (through the rest of the GUI), the value of the text field starts out as either the same it started out as before (if the user discarded the changes) or the changed value defined by the user.

Both of these things fail in some instances because of a strange behaviour: The `uicontrol`'s `'String'` property is **only updated after the `uicontrol` loses focus**. This is not a problem if the user wants to do other things on that GUI or knows how to handle this. *I can also live with my text field only updating to a meaningful numeric value after it loses focus.*
The problem is, when I close the figure via Windows' red X button in the top right corner *after changing the value of the text field, but without first clicking somewhere else*, the `'String'` value is never updated, so the *`CloseRequestFcn` doesn't notice the change* and simply closes the window. Even pausing for a whopping 100ms and then explicitly calling the text field's `Callback` from within the `CloseRequestFcn` doesn't help, it just closes without my dialog. The reverse is also true, if I do change the value, click somewhere else, and then change it back, it will display the dialog unless I first click somewhere else *again*.

So the question is this: **How do I ensure the `uicontrol` correctly updates/executes its `Callback` when I click the red X button provided by Windows?**
And bonus question: How do I execute this Callback "on the fly" in order to correct any impossible values the user enters as soon as he does (e.g. letters other than `e` and `i`)?

---

Here's the isolated part of my GUI that causes the problem, copy into a file called 'guitest.m' and run in order to test what I'm talking about.

```
function guitest

    changed = false; %// tracks changes to catch closing without saving
    startval = 1; %// the starting value

    handles.figure = figure('Resize','off','Toolbar','none','Menu',...
        'none','Name','Change text field value','CloseRequestFcn',...
        @closefig,'Visible','off'); %// not visible until fully created

    handles.textfield = uicontrol('Style','edit','Units','normalized',...
        'Parent',handles.figure,'String',startval,...
        'Position',[.4 .6 .2 .1],'Callback',@changedValue);

    handles.button = uicontrol('String','Push me','Units','normalized',...
        'Parent',handles.figure,'Position',[.4 .3 .2 .2],'Callback',@dispval);

%// all done, display GUI
    set(handles.figure,'Visible','on');

%// callback functions
    function closefig(~,~) %// Quit program
        pause(0.1);
        changedValue(handles.textfield); %// update fields
        if changed
            disp('Do you really want to close?'); %// save dialog
        else
            delete(handles.figure); %// this is used as CloseRequestFcn!
        end
    end

    function changedValue(hObject,~)
        newval = uint16(str2double(get(hObject,'String')));
        changed = (startval ~= newval);
    end

    function dispval(~,~)
        disp('With buttons inside the GUI, it works properly:');
        disp(get(handles.textfield,'String'));
        disp(changed);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will forcing a GUI focus change with [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) in your closing function provide the correct behavior? From the documentation:

> `uicontrol(uich)` gives focus to the `uicontrol` specified by the handle,
>   `uich`

For the 'bonus' you're likely going to have to leverage the underlying Java. See the article on [editbox data input validation](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/editbox-data-input-validation) from Undocumented Matlab.

Comment: That's a great idea, I will test this tomorrow when I'm back at my Matlab PC.

Comment: It doesn't work by itself, but combined with a `pause(0.001)` (probably any pause time would do) following the forced focus change, it correctly recognizes the change and updates the field. Thank you!